# Spring MVC or Restful webservice

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and Frontend development.
Should I use Spring MVC or RESTful webservice as middle tier.For frontend I want to start of with basic Javascript and then gradually move on to other Javascript frameworks.

Comment: This is too vague for this forum as it address a specific coding issue, and is instead referring to an approach to coding

Comment: Can you please advice what should the approach should be,I want to develop the middle tier in such a way that the UI development has minimum dependency on how the backend works.As I have seen in Spring MVC using the model makes the UI coupled with the backend.

Comment: Spring MVC is a framework, RESTful webservice is a concept. There is no either / or in this case.